# Runtime requirements for a published self-contained dotnet core application

Tags: .net-core

I've built a dotnet-core 2.1 console application in Visual Studio.
It's using the nuget package CommandLine and EFCore.

It's published as a self-contained bundle using

```
dotnet publish -c Release -r win7-x86
```

The output is a folder with 70MB of files among them the .exe file.

Right now I get 2 kind of errors on 2 different windows 7 machines.

```
Error:
  An assembly specified in the application dependencies manifest (MyApp.deps.json) was not found:
    package: 'CommandLineParser', version '2.3.0'
    path: 'lib/netstandard1.5/CommandLine.dll'
```

Is there any way to formally describe the requirements on Windows to make sure my application will run?

If there is an issue with the NuGet package dependencies can that be caught during build/publish?

My current **workaround** was to repackage the entire app as a .NET 4.6.1 app and after installing .NET 4.6.1 my app ran without a problem. Though the dotnet-core published app still failed.

Comment: There's 2 methods of deploying .NET Core applications. I believe you are looking for the "Self Contained" version. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/deploy-with-cli

Comment: `-r win7-x86` to `publish` makes this a self-contained deployment. That shouldn't be causing this issue.

Comment: "The output is a folder with 70MB of files among them the .exe file." What is the actual path here? Could you be using the non-publish folder by accident?

Comment: @omajid You found it, I had used the .exe file in `bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/win7-x86` rather than `bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/win7-x86/publish`

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution thanks to @omajid's comment.

**My mistake:** I had zipped the folder `bin/Release/netcoreapp2.1/win7-x86` and was running MyApp.exe in that folder.

The solution was as simple as running MyApp.exe in the subfolder `publish`